# Android runOnUiThread not async

Tags: android, multithreading

I've got this piece of code:

```
public void updateOptionLists() {
    Log.d("UI", "Called update");
    if (updating){
        return;
    }
    updating = true;
    runOnUiThread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updating = false;
                    updateOptionList();
                    scrollToLastTapped();
                    Log.d("UI","Updating");
                }
            });
    Log.d("UI", "Posted update");
}
```

What I'd expect from logcat would be something like this:

- Called update
- Posted update
- Updating

As far as I know runOnUi should be asynchronous, right? And considering that the functions called alter the views, which takes a while, this should be running asynchronous. Right?

So I look at my logcat:

- Called update
- Updating
- Posted update

Why does this happen? And how do I make sure this runs asynchronous?

Comment: you can not predict the behaviour of threads, as it depends on what gets scheduled when. may be out of 100 runs you get desired result 1 time. if you will put some sleep inside your runnable you may get desired result every time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`runOnUiThread` will execute your code on the main thread, which (in this example) also appears to be where it's called from. This explains the ordering of the log statements you see - all code is executing on a single thread, so is synchronous [per the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) (my emphasis):

> Runs the specified action on the UI thread. **If the current thread is the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately.** If the current thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue of the UI thread.

`runOnUiThread` is typically used to execute code on the main thread *from* a different (i.e. background thread). The use of this separate background thread is what will make a task asynchronous. Calling back to the UI thread at the end of that task is required if you want to modify UI with the results of your background thread calculations.

Android provides several mechanisms for doing work on a background thread and then posting back to the main thread (not all use `runOnUiThread` explicitly for the latter operation). Good things to read up on include `Thread`, `Handler`, `AsyncTask`, `Service`, etc.

Comment: Yeah, given the output you provide, my guess is it must be called from the main thread. If you provide the code you use to call this method in your question, that would help determine this for sure.

Comment: Then I'd have to provide about.... 15 levels of function calls. Not your typical UI-driven app.

Comment: Ah, in that case, I'd definitely suspect that your current thread (when making the call) is not what you think it is - that's a lot of complexity to manage! :)

Comment: Yeah.... Data-driven, own synchronization mechanism, caching mechanism... Requesting data online happens async, requesting it from cache sync. That's where I went wrong. Thanks for your explanation, got it working now ;)

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I know runOnUi should be asynchronous, right?

`runOnUiThread`, as the name states, runs on UI thread, which is a main thread of an application. It runs synchronously with other code running within that thread and asynchronously with code in other threads.
The word 'asynchronous' has no meaning without a context: some code can run asynchronously with other parts of the code, which means these parts of the code run in different threads. Saying that something 'should be asynchronous' makes no sense without this kind of context.

Answer (score 0):

is updateOptionLists running on the UI Thread?

If this is the case, i would expect this behavior to be ok.

In a normal case you use runOnUiThread from a background thread to come again to the Ui Thread..

Answer (score 0):

Because you call upadetOptionLists() on ui prosess, upadetOptionLists() and runUiThread() both run in the same thread.

To separte theam you need run content in other new thread as following

```
   public void updateOptionLists() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("UI", "Called update");
                if (updating){
                    return;
                }
                updating = true;
                runOnUiThread(
                        new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                updating = false;
                                updateOptionList();
                                scrollToLastTapped();
                                Log.d("UI","Updating");
                            }
                        });
                Log.d("UI", "Posted update");
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For accessing the view, you must be in the UI Thread (the main one). So, `runOnUiThread` will be executed on it.

You must do the long work in an other thread and only call `runOnUiThread` for little thing like changing a color or a text but not to calculating it.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue of the UI thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Answer (score 0):

Multi Threaded Programming: Theory vs Actual 
Puppy Photos Explain is the Best [pic.twitter.com/adFy17MTTI](http://t.co/adFy17MTTI)

— Cian Ó Maidín (@Cianomaidin) [6. april 2015](https://twitter.com/Cianomaidin/status/584971748757655552)

But joke aside.

If you want to test how the threads work in correlation, try:

```
runOnUiThread(
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updating = false;
                updateOptionList();
                scrollToLastTapped();
                Thread.sleep(100);
                Log.d("UI","Updating");
            }
        });
```